# Capacitor with svelte showing blank page on ios

Tags: ios, svelte, capacitor

I have a frontend that I made with Svelte. It works fine in browser. However I wanted to make an IOS app out of it with using Capacitor and for whatever reason, when I run the app in the simulator or my phone, I get a "blank" screen.

Later on I found out that it actually loads the html as when I set the background color in an inline script, it applies it and I added a text to the html and it shows.

Then I thought that it has issues with running JS or it doesn't reach the app.js file. I added a console log at the beginning of the app.js file which svelte creates and that log shows up in the log of xcode.
I was thinking that maybe it cannot render into "body" so I created a max sized div and rendered into that. In a browser it still works, but nothing on the phone..

I googled a lot and working on this issue for a day now. Could you help me?

Answer (score 2):

The issue was with routing. The webserver in the app probably (can't say for sure) can't handle the server side urls and thus won't render any component. directly adding one of my components in place of the "router", the component showed in the simulator, so I have to implement hash-based routing.